# Determine the index (row, col) of a QGridLayout item clicked

Tags: c++, qt

I have a widget that owns a QGridLayout which overrides the `mouseClickEvent`. If the grid layout was clicked (solved), I need the row and column of the item. Is there a way to convert a mouse click position to a QGridLayout index?

**Edit:** I am solving this in a terrible way currently. When I create the widget, I attach the row and column as a property of the widget and access the property thusly in `mouseClickEvent`:

```
QWidget* widget = childAt(event->pos());
if (widget)
{
    int index = ui.grid->indexOf(widget);
    QLayoutItem* item = ui.grid->itemAt(index);
    if (item->widget())
    {
        auto prop = item->widget()->property("prop");
        // convert prop to row, column
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming your layout is named `layout`, can you just use something like `layout->indexOf(layout->parentWidget()->childAt(mouse_pos))`?

Comment: QGridLayout gives a single integer as a result of `indexOf` (as in index of the internal list) rather than a row, column index (similar to a QModelIndex for a QAbstractModel)

Comment: Okay, my misunderstanding.  But you can probably use the result of the previous code snippet as the first parameter to [`QGridLayout::getItemPosition`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#getItemPosition).

Comment: Yes! That should work. I misread that function when reading the documentation. Thank you